# Question about whether a series converges almost surely

Tags: probability, probability-theory, almost-everywhere

We are given that $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are iid $\text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$. Then let $Y_n=X_n/n^{\theta},\ \theta>0$. The question is to say whether $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nY_i$ converges almost surely or not.

Towards a solution, I note that if $\theta>1$, then since the sum is dominated by $\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i^\theta$ which has a finite limit, $S_n$ also converges, and hence in particular, converges almost surely. But for the $0<\theta\le 1$ case, I am stuck. No bound I am considering is being strong enough to point me towards a contradiction (or towards a affirmative answer, which I have a hunch is not the case, but I might be wrong).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is almost surely?

Comment: @BobDobbs In a probability space $(\Omega,P), P(\Omega)=1$ we say $X_n\rightarrow X$ almost surely if $P(\{x: X_n(x)\nrightarrow X(x)\})=0$

Comment: In other word the set of point where it does not converge has measure 0, but since it is probability we say the probability of the set is 0.

Comment: What is $X_n$? A single variable or what else?

Comment: @callculus42 A sequence of random variables.

Comment: Wouldn't be $X_i \ \ \forall \ i\in\{1, 2, ..., n\}$  a better definition? For me $X_n$ represents something like the sum of $n$ random variables or something similar.

Comment: Are you familiar with Kolmogorov's three series theorem?

Comment: @DominikKutek I am, but I am not sure if we are allowed to use that. This is in preparation for an exam for my probability course, and we haven't actually covered that.

Comment: Where does this convergence live? I assume these are all Real-valued RVs. I  mean, if it converges and Y is its limit , does Y live in a space of Real-valued RVs?

Comment: @MSIS Yes that is true afair.